# Проблемы с прозрачностью C# PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

[image: Глюки с прозрачностью]

Есть форма 1. На ней лежит `Panel` в которой растянут `WebBrowser 2`.
Когда помещаю сверху `PictureBox` c прозрачностью она просвечивает до `Panel` (специально задал цвет) игнорируя `WebBrowser`.

Кто сталкивался подскажите как можно решить данную проблему.

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: @VladD - По моему WinForms, просто не так давно на C# начал кодить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что прозрачность в WinForms - ненастоящая.

`BackColor = Transparent` означает на самом деле "цвет фона такой же, как цвет фона родителя". А не "не рисовать вообще ничего", как обычно ожидают от прозрачности.

В вашем случае - при использовании именно `PictireBox` с картинкой в нем - есть [обходной путь](http://www.richardhyland.com/diary/2009/05/26/how-to-truely-make-a-picturebox-background-transparent/). Можно ограничить отрисовку самого `PictireBox` обласью, совпадающей по форме с непрозрачной частью картинки:

```
public static System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath BuildTransparencyPath(Image im)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(im);
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
    Color mask = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);

    for (x = 0; x <= bmp.Width - 1; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y <= bmp.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            if (!bmp.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(mask))
            {
                gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
            }
        }
    }
    bmp.Dispose();
    return gp;
}  

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = BuildTransparencyPath(pictureBox1.Image);
    pictureBox1.Region = new Region(gp);
}
```

Выглядеть результат будет примерно так ([сам png взят из википедии, кубики замылены в оригинале](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#/media/File:PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в этом решении не будет работать полупрозрачность по краям. Но лучшего результата в WinForms получить нельзя. Если нужна честная полупрозрачность - переходите на WPF.

Comment: Если переопределять отрисовку, то можно и ничего не рисовать... Кстати, это ж идея - надо попробовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy это не переопределение отрисовки. это извлечение из картинки области, которую надо рисовать :)

Comment: @Qwertiy хотя можно наверное переопределить отрисовку OnPaintBackground у панели - но не уверен, что это сработает

Comment: У PictureBox'а. Панель-то зачем трогать?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, у него - опечатался. сильно опечатался :)

Comment: @PashaPash Всё конечно замечательно, но! PictureBox просвечивает только через WebBrowser, т.е. если как в PhotoShop разложить на слои то 1. слой форма 2. слой Панель 3. слой WebBrowser 4. слой PictureBox. На Panel ImageBox с Png картинкой и BackgroundColor transparent ложиться замечательно, никаких глюков. Но проблема в том что pictureBox как бы игнорирует существование WebBrowser и просвечивает через него до слоя Panel.

Comment: @VladimirH потому что отрисовкой панели и остальных компонентов занимаются сами winforms/winapi, c использованием того же графического контекста. они могут взять пиксель, отрисованный парентом (панелью) и использовать его для прозрачности чайлда. а отрисовкой WebBrowser занимается IE. с точки зрения вашего приложения - это большой черный ящик. WinForms вообще не в курсе что он там нарисовал.